# linked list sort function only loops once

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

i have a singly linked list that i am trying to sort from least to greatest by price. here is what i have so far

```
struct part {
    char* name;
    float price;
    int quantity;
    struct part *next;
};

typedef struct part partType;

partType *sort_price(partType **item) {

    int check = 0;        

    if ( *item == NULL || (*item)->next == NULL ) 
        return *item;
    else {

        partType *temp1 = *item;
        partType *temp2 = (*item)->next;

      do{
        check = 0;
        while ( temp2 != NULL && temp2->next != NULL ){
            if (temp2->price > temp2->next->price){
                temp1->next = temp2->next;
                temp2->next = temp2->next->next;
                temp1->next->next = temp2;
                check = 1;
            }
            temp1 = temp2;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
       }while (check == 1);
    }
    return *item;
}
```

the list is already populated but when i call the sort function it only swaps the first two nodes that satisfy the condition in the if statement. I dont understand why it doesnt do the check again after the two temp pointers are incremented.

Comment: There is no way you can sort with one loop. None...

Comment: What did you discover when you stepped through your program in a debugger, or when you added print statements to observe the values of intermediate variables?

Comment: Sorting a linked list. Yikes. Unless this is homework, there are better was of doing this than writing your own bubble sort implementation.

Comment: @UmNyobe: Not true.  See e.g. http://ideone.com/TgWpt.

Comment: some good examples of implementations (http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/986/) have a look there and try to see what you are doing wrong. best way to learn :)

Comment: the current code wont work at all since it will only do two or no swaps and then exit, which was you problem to start with

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing only one iteration of Bubble sort. You need to repeat till there is a run which doesn't chance the ordering....

Note that you have some mistakes too... The first element is not affected by your algorithm. so  if I fetch `2->1` I would obtain `2->1` instead of `1->2`. Similarly the element at `temp1` is not affected either.

So if I run on `4->3->2->1`

`t1= 4 ,t2 = 3, t2->next = 2` then swap `t1= 4 ,t2 = 2, t2->next = 3`

`t1= 2 ,t2 = 3, t2->next = 1` then swap `t1= 2 ,t2 = 1, t2->next = 3`

And the result is

```
 4->2->1->3
```

***EDIT***
The condition is simple. Add a variable `changeOccured`
like

```
   int changeOccured = 1;
   while( changeOccured){
        changeOccured = 0;
        // one run of bubble
            if (temp2->price > temp2->next->price){
              //add this when the if succeed
              changeOccured = 1;
           }

   }
```

Comment: i cant think of the condition i would need to put in an outer loop that would make it run until completion.

Comment: sorry i meant to say that i am aware i havent accounted for the head node being greater. i am still unsure on how to implement that as well.

Comment: @TristanPearce Go look at a canonical *pseudo-code* implementation (such as one found on Wikipedia, a good data-structure book, etc). Then think how that can be converted to C.

Comment: i already had that in and it didnt seem to do anything. the sort still only ran through once. can you look at edited code and tell me why that also didnt help?

Comment: I agree with pst, look at the pseudocode... in your edit when you reach the end of the list check =0 ,  temp2 = NULL so it stops prematurely. Also Use a debugger

Answer (score 0):

You can use any inplace sorts like `MergeSort`.

If you know the key space you can also go for `Counting Sort`. Good starting point is .[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Answer (score 0):

If `*item == NULL` your example will crash, since you obtain `temp2` **before** checking this.

And, of course, it's impossible to sort the list within one pass, simply because there's no linear sorting algorithm.

You may however split it and sort recursively (merge sort). This "would look" like a single list pass (merge).

Comment: i am wondering what outer loop do i need that it will sort the list with just one call of the function. that is where i am stuck